# Can't figure out what css/bootsrap statment is effecting layout of form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I am trying to put a `border` and `background-color` behind a form, but when I try to do so, the form is set to the right and I am not sure which piece of my code is doing this.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/gpakfdtL/ , please ignore the django code - I figured I would leave those elements in the example in case they were the source of my problem.

Here is an example of what I would want it to look like: https://jsfiddle.net/w8py15kg/1/ (not exactly, but the form is centered).

Can anyone figure out why my form is being set to the right like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fixed `width`. I tried changing it to `100%` and it worked.

Here you have it: https://jsfiddle.net/5gw7na4z/

```
#job_search_form {
    margin: 50px auto 50px auto;
    width: 100%; <--- HERE
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 10px solid black;
    padding: 50px;
}
```